# Replicating the rotation of one game object on another game object using Quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day everybody. I'm trying to learn more about rotations in unity and would appreciate some help. I have been bashing my head over this problem for a while now. The purpose of the script I've created is to take another game objects transform in and replicate the difference in rotations of that transform on the game object the script is attached too.

The script needs to be able to follow each independent axis rotation solely, or two of the axes, or even all three. The code below works if all three of the axes are monitored, when the x and z axis are solely monitored, when the y and z axis are solely monitored, but NOT when the x and y axis are solely monitored (The game object that's following (with the script attached)) generates a value for the z axis when trying to rotate just the x and y axis.

It becomes clear that whenever I'm trying to replicate the rotation of two of the axes and the z axis is not one of those axes I'm running into issues. I have done this with quaternions to avoid gimbal lock. I do believe there is an issue with the implementation of my w axis when creating the Quaternion (Which represents the rotation I want to apply to the Game object).

If anyone may provide some insight I'd be very grateful, I am a junior developer and have only started working with unity this year.

Please find the code below

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class RotationSync2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    public Transform ExternalTransform;

    private Quaternion PreviousExternalTransform;
    private Quaternion RotationDifference;
    private Quaternion Temp = new Quaternion();
    private Quaternion PreviousTemp;

    private float xToUse;
    private float yToUse;
    private float zToUse;

    private bool RotationComplete = false;
   
    [HideInInspector] public bool rotateX;
    [HideInInspector] public bool rotateY;
    [HideInInspector] public bool rotateZ;

    [HideInInspector]  public bool InvertX;
    [HideInInspector]  public bool InvertY;
    [HideInInspector]  public bool InvertZ;

    [HideInInspector] public float percentageOfRotationToFollowX = 1f;
    [HideInInspector] public float percentageOfRotationToFollowY = 1f;
    [HideInInspector] public float percentageOfRotationToFollowZ = 1f;

    private float rotationToSetX;
    private float rotationToSetY;
    private float rotationToSetZ;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PreviousExternalTransform = ExternalTransform.rotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ClearPreviousRotationValues();
        BuildQuarternion();
        FindRotateDifference();
        SetRotationValues();
        SetRotations();
    }

    public void ClearPreviousRotationValues()
    {
        rotationToSetX = 0;
        rotationToSetY = 0;
        rotationToSetZ = 0;
    }

    private void BuildQuarternion()
    {
        if (ExternalTransform.rotation.x == PreviousExternalTransform.x && rotateX)
        {
            Temp.x = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            Temp.x = ExternalTransform.rotation.x;
        }

        if (ExternalTransform.rotation.y == PreviousExternalTransform.y && rotateY)
        {
            Temp.y = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            Temp.y = ExternalTransform.rotation.y;
        }
        if (ExternalTransform.rotation.z == PreviousExternalTransform.z && rotateZ)
        {
            Temp.z = 0f;
        }

        else
        {
            Temp.z = ExternalTransform.rotation.z;
        }
        Temp.w = ExternalTransform.rotation.w;

    }

    private void FindRotateDifference()
    {
        Quaternion a = Quaternion.identity * Quaternion.Inverse(Temp);
        Quaternion b = Quaternion.identity * Quaternion.Inverse(PreviousTemp);


        if (ExternalTransform.rotation != PreviousExternalTransform && PreviousTemp != null)
        {
            RotationDifference = b * Quaternion.Inverse(a);
            RotationComplete = false;
        }
        PreviousTemp = Temp;
        PreviousExternalTransform = ExternalTransform.rotation;

        if (PreviousTemp == null)
        {
            return;
        }

    }
    public void SetRotationValues()
    {
        if (rotateX) //Checks if this axis is being used 
        {
            if (InvertX)
            {
                rotationToSetX = (RotationDifference.x * percentageOfRotationToFollowX) * -1; // set the rotation to the value of the given transform * the percentage to follow * -1 to invert it
            }
            else
            {
                rotationToSetX = RotationDifference.x * percentageOfRotationToFollowX; // set the rotation to the value of the given transform * the percentage to follow
            }

        }
        if (rotateY)
        {
            if (InvertY)
            {
                rotationToSetY = (RotationDifference.y * percentageOfRotationToFollowY) * -1;
            }
            else
            {
                rotationToSetY = RotationDifference.y * percentageOfRotationToFollowY;
            }
        }
        if (rotateZ)
        {
            if (InvertZ)
            {
                rotationToSetZ = (RotationDifference.z * percentageOfRotationToFollowZ) * -1;
            }
            else
            {
                rotationToSetZ = RotationDifference.z * percentageOfRotationToFollowZ;
            }
        }
    }



    public void SetRotations() //Checks which of axis' rotation the transform should follow of the given transform and applies the respective rotations.
    {
        if (RotationComplete == false)
        {
            if (rotateX && rotateY && rotateZ)
            {
                transform.rotation *= new Quaternion(rotationToSetX, rotationToSetY, rotationToSetZ, RotationDifference.w);
            }
            else if (rotateX && rotateY)
            {
                transform.rotation *= new Quaternion(rotationToSetX, rotationToSetY, 0f, RotationDifference.w);
            }
            else if (rotateX && rotateZ)
            {
                transform.rotation *= new Quaternion(rotationToSetX,0f, rotationToSetZ, RotationDifference.w);
            }
            else if (rotateY && rotateZ)
            {
                transform.rotation *= new Quaternion(0f, rotationToSetY, rotationToSetZ, RotationDifference.w);
            }
            else if (rotateX)
            {
                transform.rotation *= new Quaternion(rotationToSetX, 0f, 0f, RotationDifference.w);
            }
            else if (rotateY)
            {
                transform.rotation *= new Quaternion(0f, rotationToSetY, 0f, RotationDifference.w);
            }
            else if (rotateZ)
            {
                transform.rotation *= new Quaternion(0f, 0f, rotationToSetZ, RotationDifference.w);
            }
            RotationComplete = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are the X,Y,Z ment to be in global world space or in local space relative to the individual objects? And in general: rotations are not as simple as movements ... if you have a certain rotation around multiple axes (an arbitrary vector) .. then what exactly is the expected outcome if you split up this rotation and only take Y or X? This can't be translated as easily as e.g. movements where you can clearly split up into the 3D axes

Comment: Hey, x,y,z are meant to be in the local space relative to just the objects rotations. Yeah I've been given this task and its proved extremely difficult due to not being able to split the rotation axes up (like movement). I was also testing this code with [ExecuteInEditMode]. Turns out the behaviour is completely different to when the application is actually running :(

Comment: The issue with `ExecuteInEditMode` is that `Start` is not called  and Update is only called in certain intervals when something in the scene is changed

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicated this a lot and also note that you **never** want to directly access/assign the individual components of a `Quaternion` except you are absolutely sure what you are doing!
The components `x`, `y`, `z` alone are not the rotation Euler axes!

I don't know if I fully understand your use case but it sounds to me like what you have/want is

- There are two objects `A` and `B`
- Both have different rotations when starting the app
- Whenever object `A` is rotated you want to perform the same rotation also on object `B` but maintaining the original rotation difference
- additionally there is the option to deactivate or invert individual axes

I think this is a use case where it is actually allowed/the only chance to go through Euler axes instead of Quaternion!

So what you actually want to do is

1. get the delta rotation of object `A` between the last and current frame in its local space for each axis individually
2. assign this same delta rotation(s) to object `B` in its local space

So I think I would do something like

```
public Transform ExternalTransform;

[HideInInspector] public bool rotateX;
[HideInInspector] public bool rotateY;
[HideInInspector] public bool rotateZ;

[HideInInspector]  public bool InvertX;
[HideInInspector]  public bool InvertY;
[HideInInspector]  public bool InvertZ;

[HideInInspector] [Min(0)] public float percentageOfRotationToFollowX = 1f;
[HideInInspector] [Min(0)] public float percentageOfRotationToFollowY = 1f;
[HideInInspector] [Min(0)] public float percentageOfRotationToFollowZ = 1f;

private Vector3 lastExternalEuler;

private void Awake ()
{
    lastExternalEuler = NormalizeEuler(ExternalTransform.localEulerAngles);
} 

// Note: I would use LateUpdate so the object is already rotated for this frame
private void LateUpdate ()
{
    var currentExternalEuler = NormalizeEuler (ExternalTransform.localEulerAngles);
    var localDelta = NormalizeEulerDelta(currentExternalEuler - lastExternalEuler);

    localDelta = ApplySettings(localDelta);

    // And then either 
    transform.Rotate(localDelta);
    // or if you want to do something else like smoothing later on
    //transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(localDelta);

    lastExternalEuler = currentExternalEuler;
}

// Map all Euler axes into the positive range between 0 and 360
private static Vector3 NormalizeEuler (Vector3 euler)
{
    while(euler.x >= 360f) euler.x -= 360;
    while(euler.x < 0f) euler.x += 360;
    while(euler.y >= 360f) euler.y -= 360;
    while(euler.y < 0f) euler.y += 360;
    while(euler.z >= 360f) euler.z -= 360;
    while(euler.z < 0f) euler.z += 360;

    return euler;
}

// map the delta axes into range between -180 and 180
private static Vector3 NormalizeEulerDelta (Vector3 delta)
{
    if(delta.x > 180) delta.x = -180 - (180 - delta.x);
    if(delta.x < -180) delta.x = -(180 + delta.x);
    if(delta.x > 180) delta.y = -180 - (180 - delta.y);
    if(delta.y < -180) delta.y = -(180 + delta.y);
    if(delta.x > 180) delta.z = -180 - (180 - delta.z);
    if(delta.z < -180) delta.z = -(180 + delta.z);

    return delta;
}

private static Vector3 ApplySettings (Vector3 delta)
{
    delta.x = rotateX ? delta.x : 0f;
    delta.y = rotateY ? delta.y : 0f;
    delta.z = rotateZ ? delta.z : 0f;


    delta.x *= invertX ? -1 : 1;
    delta.y *= invertY ? -1 : 1;
    delta.z *= invertZ ? -1 : 1;

    delta.x *= percentageOfRotationToFollowX;
    delta.y *= percentageOfRotationToFollowY;
    delta.z *= percentageOfRotationToFollowZ;

    return delta;
}
```

Though basically instead of having individual flags and values

```
rotateX
invertX
percantageX
```

why not rather have one single

```
public float multiplicatorX = 1f;
```

and accordingly for the other axes? ;)

You only need this single value and it can be `0` (rotateX = false) it can be negative (invertX = true) and it can be an arbitrary percentage

---

*Note: Typed on the phone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to assess this problem with me. I had previously tried to normalize the individual Euler axes, I can really appreciate your implementation. I have tested the code, the only issue (Which I can hopefully resolve) is that the script continuously applies the set rotation each frame. So if I apply 15 degrees to the x axis on the first object the second object gets that value applied to it every frame even if the first object is no longer rotating. I am going to go through the code in more detail now.

Comment: And thank you for the idea of managing both the strength percentages and bool values together, brilliant.

Comment: @MatthewLeslie oh darn :D I forgot a simple but quite important thing: I never update `lastExternalEuler` ;) I added it now

Comment: Haha I noticed that and I updated it at the end of every LateUpdate() to the currentExternalEuler. The issue that then arises, is when the x axis rotates out of the bounds of 0 and +90 the following object seems to invert against the object it should be following. If I select to rotate x & y together (without z) there is still a generated z value which leads to the object to not mimic the rotation of the other. Another issue for example is if I rotate just the y axis, when the axis value is greater than 360 it also looses the intended behaviour. I'll let you know if I come up with something.